# Browser resize service

Tags: javascript, angular.js

In AngularJS, I currently have a directive and 2 services which permit me to bind the window resize event, and broadcast it to my application.

I would like to know if you could see anything that could be improved in my code, in term of optimization, naming or possible cross browser issues.

I have:

- A directive which binds resize event. It will broadcast the event 300ms after the last resize (to avoid flood).
- A factory to get window's dimensions
- A service to detect browser's name (chrome, safari, etc...). In this case, it is used to target Safari which doesn't calculate window's dimensions the same way.

[Here is a plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ephqGM1OiR8zsxApSrkR?p=preview) to illustrate the code.

### Detect Browser Service

```
/*
 * Detects on which browser the user is navigating
 *
 * Usage:
 * var browser = detectBrowser();
 *
 */
commonApp.service('detectBrowser', ['$window', 
    function( $window ) {

        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22947535/how-to-detect-browser-using-angular
        return function() {
            var userAgent = $window.navigator.userAgent,
                browsers  = { 
                    chrome  : /chrome/i,
                    safari  : /safari/i,
                    firefox : /firefox/i,
                    ie      : /internet explorer/i
                };

            for ( var key in browsers ) {
                if ( browsers[key].test(userAgent) ) {
                    return key;
                }
            }

            return 'unknown';
        }
    }]);
```

### Window Dimensions Factory

```
/*
 * Get window height and width
 *
 * Usage:
 * windowDimensions.height();
 * windowDimensions.width();
 *
 */
commonApp.factory('windowDimensions', ['$window', 'detectBrowser', 
    function( $window, detectBrowser ) {
        var browser = detectBrowser();

        return {
            height: function() {
                return ( browser === 'safari' ) 
                          ? document.documentElement.clientHeight 
                          : window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight
            },

            width : function() {
                return ( browser === 'safari' ) 
                          ? document.documentElement.clientWidth 
                          : window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth
            }
        }
    }]);
```

### Window Resize Event Directive

```
/*
 * Watch window resizing event to set new window dimensions,
 * and broadcast the event to the app
 *
 * Usage:
 * <html watch-window-resize>...</html>
 *
 * Bind the resize event:
   $scope.$on('watchWindowResize::resize', function() {
       // Do something
   });
 *
 */
app.directive('watchWindowResize', ['$window', '$timeout', 'windowDimensions', 
    function( $window, $timeout, windowDimensions ) {

        return {
            link: function( $scope ) {
                // Get window's dimensions
                $scope.getDimensions = function() {

                    // Namespacing events with name of directive + event to avoid collisions
                    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23272169/what-is-the-best-way-to-bind-to-a-global-event-in-a-angularjs-directive
                    $scope.$broadcast('watchWindowResize::resize', {
                        height: windowDimensions.height(),
                        width : windowDimensions.width()
                    });
                }

                // On window resize...
                angular.element($window).on('resize', function( e ) {

                    // Reset timeout
                    $timeout.cancel($scope.resizing);

                    // Add a timeout to not call the resizing function every pixel
                    $scope.resizing = $timeout( function() {

                        $scope.getDimensions();
                    }, 300);
                });
            }
        }
    }]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fun question,

I am not sure why you think you need a special treatment for Safari, I could not find any reference to that on the webs. So if you only need the browser code for that part, then I would drop it and simply go for

```
/*
 * Get window height and width
 *
 * Usage:
 * windowDimensions.height();
 * windowDimensions.width();
 *
 */
app.factory('windowDimensions', ['$window',
  function($window) {
    return {
      height: function() {
        return window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight;
      },
      width: function() {
        return window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

From a naming perspective I would suggest these changes:

- `getDimensions` -> broadcastDimensions (since that is really what you are doing there)
- `$scope.resizing` -> `$scope.resizingTimer` (to reduce potential confusion, `resizing` is a verb so one would expect `resizing` to do something instead of merely being a timer)
- `300` -> `var delayTime = 300; //Broadcast 300ms after the last resize to avoid flood`

Other than that, all is well besides a few missing semicolons.
You can test my fork on Safari if you wish, it worked for me:
http://plnkr.co/edit/SY8pnX3ae4YtWErno5f0?p=preview

Comment: "Fun question" ? :D By the way thanks for your answer, naming is really not my highest quality as english is not my mother language and I have some troubles to find the right vocabulary. Concerning Safari, I had problems on a previous project with media queries and real window's width. I just don't remember if it was in safari mobile devices (I could not test it right now), because you are right for latest Safari browser, it doesn't change anything. I updated the plunkr with your code and some media queries (also console log window's width) http://plnkr.co/edit/ephqGM1OiR8zsxApSrkR?p=preview

Comment: Also, why putting `delayTime` inside a variable as I am using it only once? My goal is not to permit to change this delay inside the directive via an option. Is there a reason behind?

Comment: I tested this on my iPhone 5, it worked for me. As for `delayTime`, you could also just put `300 /*ms delay*/` or something

Comment: I will check this when I have access to more Safari devices and I come back to you. I am quite sure that I did this for a good purpose ^^